# gulp выбрасывает ошибку связанную с gulp-imagemin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

код ошибки

```
events.js:142
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\adm\Desktop\projects\test\img\Thumbs.db'
at Error (native)
```

В первый раз gulp-imagemin сжал картинки нормально, потом стал выкидывать ошибку. Может в gulpfile.js что-то не так?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

gulp.task('stylus', function() {

gulp.src('stylus/style.styl')
     .pipe(stylus({
        'include css': true,
        compress: true
    }))
     .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['> 1%']
        }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
     .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('jade', function(){

gulp.src(['jade/index.jade', 'jade/main.jade'])
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));

 });

 gulp.task('ser', function() {
  browserSync.init(['*.html', 'css/*.css'], {
    server: {
        baseDir: './',
     }
   });
});

gulp.task('img', function() {
        gulp.src('img-full/*')
            .pipe(imagemin({
                    progressive: true,
                    svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
                    use: [pngquant()]
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./img'));
 });

 gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('stylus/**/*.styl', ['stylus']);
    gulp.watch('jade/*.jade', ['jade']);
  });


  gulp.task('default',['ser', 'jade', 'stylus', 'img', 'watch']);
```

Если из таска убрать вызов 'img' то нормально работает без ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он наверно хочеть сжать thumb file. так что в `gulp.src(['img-full/**/*.jpg','img-full/**/*.png])`
решит вашу проблему

Comment: Точно, спасибо.